# Live VM snapshot without pausing the VM

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, virtualization

Which virtualization systems support taking a snapshot of a running VM **without pausing the VM?**

As far as I know, both VMware and VirtualBox pause a VM while taking a live snapshot.

Technically it should be possible to let the VM run while taking the snapshot. The software must record all changes to the VM disks that occur while taking the snapshot, and in the end, apply those changes to the disk images that were just created.

Also, I'm not sure how to search this question on Google. If I search for `live VM snapshot VirtualBox`, I'm getting descriptions of how to take a snapshot of a running machine. I know how to do that, but I want to take a snapshot that does not interrupt the machine while the snapshot is taken.

Comment: Interesting, but I forsee problems. The reason the VM pauses is because there is heavy disk I/O, if instead you tried to record every event that happens twice (one for the live machine and one for the delta) you would surely slow the machine down.

Comment: Hyper-V does live snapshots. If you hit the Checkpoint button, it takes a snapshot without interrupting the virtual machine at all.

Answer (score 1):

The command for virtualbox is

`VBoxManage snapshot "<Box Name|UUID>" take "<Snapshot Name>" --description "<description>" --live`

However, I read that there are some instances where performing the operation could put the machine in a state of limbo where you would need to reboot the machine on recovery. I, personally, have not attempted to pull back a snap and run it to see what, if anything is harmed by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

#### Hyper-V supports live snapshots.

- Client Hyper-V, included in Windows 8 Pro and Windows 10 Pro, can take snapshots without interrupting execution of the virtual machine or its applications. Client Hyper-V uses the same underpinning technology as Microsoft's datacenter-grade Windows Server Hyper-V virtualization solution. (You'll need to upgrade your OS to access this feature if you're not running a Pro edition of Windows; this will cost US$99.)
- I did run into a problem testing this feature on Windows 10 Pro: if the Guest Services in the guest OS is not up to date, you might get an error when doing this and the snapshot would fail. I'm not sure how to fix this issue.